# is it possible to use WhereIn / WhereNull or Condition on firstOrNew, firstOrCreate, updateOrCreate?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

im trying to understanding about laravel and shorten my code

firstOrNew, firstOrCreate, updateOrCreate
from what ive been reading you can do simple condition like :

**example 1**

condition where email matched then updateOrCreate:

```
$user = User::updateOrCreate(
    ['email' =>  request('email')],
    ['name' => request('name')]
);
```

**example 2** -  this is what ive been usually code my update / create

but is it possible to use whereNull, whereIn or other conditions on updateOrCreate like this example 2 ?

```
$user = User::whereNull( 'email' )->first();

$vars =
[
'email' => request('email'),
'name' => request('name')
];

if($user){
    $user->update($vars);
}else{
    $user = User::create($vars);
}
```

is example 2 the best approach or shorter code for update and creating entry in database ?

thanks if anyone willing to help

Answer (score 1):

You could use all eloquent functions/conditions that you need before `updateOrCreate`.

```
/**
 * Create or update a record matching the attributes, and fill it with values.
 *
 * @param  array  $attributes
 * @param  array  $values
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|static
 */
public function updateOrCreate(array $attributes, array $values = [])
{
    return tap($this->firstOrNew($attributes), function ($instance) use ($values) {
        $instance->fill($values)->save();
    });
}
```

And

```
/**
 * Get the first record matching the attributes or instantiate it.
 *
 * @param  array  $attributes
 * @param  array  $values
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|static
 */
public function firstOrNew(array $attributes, array $values = [])
{
    if (! is_null($instance = $this->where($attributes)->first())) {
        return $instance;
    }

    return $this->newModelInstance($attributes + $values);
}
```

Comment: sorry im not that advance in laravel, i want to ask is this override the existing laravel function firstOrNew / updateOrCreate and put it in model user ?

Comment: No, it's not override. It's laravel functions into default eloquent builder not inside model.

I mean, you could use something like 
`YourModel::where(...)->whereIn(...)->updateOrCreate(...)`

Comment: thanks for answering, i will try it again
somehow my query keep create new record instead of updating

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$user = User::whereIn('condition', 'value')->firstOrCreate(
    ['email' =>  request('email')],
    ['name' => request('name')]
);
```